# how to set required parameters for a consumer in apache camel's google mail component

Tags: java, apache-camel, gmail-api

I am trying to use the camel's [google-mail component](http://camel.apache.org/googlemail.html) to fetch the latest mails from my account. Specifically, I am using the `history` endpoint prefix with the list endpoint. My route looks like this

```
<route id="parseNewMails">
        <from uri="g-mail://history/list?userId=me&amp;consumer.delay=10000"/>
        <!-- <setHeader headerName="CamelGoogleMail.startHistoryId">
            <constant>2938321</constant>
        </setHeader> -->
        <to uri="file://output1"/>
</route>
```

The [Google Mail Api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) specifies that I can use parameters like `startHistoryId`, `labelId` etc... to control the output.But, how do I pass them in the URI?

```
<from uri="g-mail://history/list?userId=me&amp;CamelGoogleMail.startHistoryId=291234&amp;consumer.delay=10000"/>
```

OR

```
<from uri="g-mail://history/list?userId=me&amp;startHistoryId=291234&amp;consumer.delay=10000"/>
```

does not work. It throws this error:

```
 Failed to resolve endpoint: g-mail://history/list?CamelGoogleMail.startHistoryId=2938321&consumer.delay=10000&userId=me due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{CamelGoogleMail.startHistoryId=2938321}]
```

**EDIT**::
I have the required dependency added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-google-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and the component configured

```
<bean id="g-mail" class="org.apache.camel.component.google.mail.GoogleMailComponent">
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.google.mail.GoogleMailConfiguration">
            <property name="accessToken" value="xxx" />
            <property name="applicationName" value="Simple Sample" />
            <property name="clientId" value="xxx" />
            <property name="clientSecret" value="xxx" />
            <property name="refreshToken" value="xxx" />
            <property name="scopes" value="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels" />
            <!-- <property name="p12FileName" value="" />
            <property name="user" value="" /> -->
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note that the history prefix and the list endpoint works. Its just that I cannot specify the startHistoryId parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the value of startHistoryId in a camel header. It should work.

> Any URI option can be provided in a message header for producer
>   endpoints with a CamelGoogleMail. prefix.

Comment: I have the dependency added. the reason I use g-mail is coz that's the id of the bean I have used to configure the google-mail component. I have updated the original question and added the relevant snippet.

Comment: Please set the value of startHistoryId in a camel header. It should work. "Any URI option can be provided in a message header for producer endpoints with a CamelGoogleMail. prefix."

Comment: But since `from` is the first line in a route, how can I set a header before that?

Comment: Oops, my bad. Actually looking at the error I think there is no issue in setting this value. Can you try changing the camel version and just to check whether it works in different version ?